# Data annotation validation error message show up right away. EF 4.2/MVC3

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm having an issue with my required data annotations messages showing up right away in my edit form even though there is data in the controls.  If I click save everything works fine and if I give focus to the controls that have the error displayed and then change focus to another control the error message goes away... This seems only to be the issue in my edit form, create doesn't have the same issue.

I'm using EF 4.2 with the dbcontext generator and using the validation data annotations via a metadata class.  My class points to the metadata class using the metadataType attribute. class below:

```
<MetadataType(GetType(PersonsMetaData))>
Partial Public Class Persons
End Class

Public Class PersonsMetaData

  Private mPersonFirstName As Object
  Private mPersonLastName As Object
  Private mPersonPrimaryEmail As Object

<Required()> _
Public Property PersonFirstName As Object
    Get
        Return mPersonFirstName
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        mPersonFirstName = value
    End Set
End Property

<Required()> _
Public Property PersonLastName As Object
    Get
        Return mPersonLastName
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        mPersonLastName = value
    End Set
End Property

<Required()> _
Public Property PersonPrimaryEmail As Object
    Get
        Return mPersonPrimaryEmail
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        mPersonPrimaryEmail = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

My edit view has be generated using the mvc 3 framework.

Any advice would be appreciated